# Outlook 2010 sends .oft as plain text

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

The title pretty much describes the problem. oft opens just fine, but when you send it the message comes with no styles and with images as attachments. Is there any way to make Outlook 2010 send oft properly?

Comment: something I found via google, but I have no idea if it works... File - Options - Mail - "Relies and Forward". deselected "Preface Comments with"

Comment: I've seen that suggestion too, but when I checked the settings, it turned out that this option was deselected by default.

Comment: ok, another idea... the person receiving doesn't have a correct file association for .oft files. If you change the file association to microsoft outlook, does it work then?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to bump an old post but I was having a similar issue for weeks and couldn't find a solution anywhere.

I would create a message as html in Outlook 2010 and save as .oft, but it would subsequently open as plain text. Some users could use my template, for others it would open but send as plain text, for some it would open as plain text - and there was no obvious pattern to it!

The issue? I had selected to digitally sign the .oft when I saved it (I have my Outlook configured to automatically add my digital signature to all messages - company policy). When you open a .oft it will select 'sign' and when you save it the template may not work correctly.

De-select 'sign' before saving the .oft. If you amend the template later you must ensure that you de-select it before saving or you will break your template.

I hope this helps someone out there!

Note: I am using Windows 7 and Outlook 2010.

Comment: This can also happen if the template wasn't signed and you're now signing all emails by default. Either way, it's related to signing.